# What is the name of this item contact pin?

Tags: power-electronics, light, pins, contact

[image]I am making a box with lights inside of it. These lights are UVC lights, which will sanitize any items put inside. I have attached a photo; I would like to know the name of this item. I know it is some contact pin, but I am not sure which. Must I have this be custom made? As you can see, there is something gold on the right side of each photo; that is what I am looking for. What is the name of that item? if you would like more the product name is Tidie, they are on Indigogo

[image: As you can see, there is something gold on the right side of each photo; that is what I am looking for. What is the name of that item?][image: There is another photo, if you would like more the product name is Tidie, they are on Indigogo]

Comment: The resolution is so low that I can't see any details.  Post a zoomed-in image of what you area talking about.  In general, that type of connector with two big guide pins is called a blind-mate connector.

Comment: The technical term is "failure point" ;-)   More seriously it looks like some sort of sprung finger contact, though it's possible what we are seeing are pads hit by fat "pogo" or "spring pin" contacts on the lid.  The designers seem to have gone for aesthetic over affordability or durability.

Comment: @AnalogKid Added another photo, talking about the gold pin for the transfer of electricity.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, I like the way it looks. By the way, the use of this is for the transfer of electricity from my top lid to the bottom. Do you think I should be a failure point to a sprung finger contact?

Answer (score 1):

You can get [spring loaded pins](https://microem.ru/files/2013/01/millmax-spring-loaded-contacts.pdf) and pin arrays, and target pins and arrays that might do that job for you.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can make it look like there? It looks very nice in the image, and can this transfer electricity?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: So let me explain everything to you. I am making a box that has a hinge and a lid. There will be a UVC light on the lid;  and on the bottom portion of the box, there will be a grill gate. This grill gate is what you put your phone or object on to sanitize; there is another UVC light on the bottom under the grill grate. It will be hard to wire a box that opens and closes, so my idea is to use metal, so when the lid is shut, two metal poles, two positive and two negatives, will meet. This will cause energy transfer, which will then power the bulb on the lid without any wires.

Comment: so if there are springs, this will not work; in the photo, there is a very nice-looking contact plate; as I mentioned, I want this to look professional. So what can I use for there to be no springs or anything

Comment: Obviously there has to be some compliance on one side or the other (or both) or the contacts will not be reliable. If you spend the money to have custom tooling made you can have custom contacts made, all up to you and your mechanical engineering folks.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany-, I see. Thanks for the insight. I am just starting my business, so it's just me, but we will see. If I have more questions, do you mind if I ask you?